# How to synchronize object types sent from Web API backend to React/Redux frontend

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-web-api, redux

I have written a backend for my app on .net, that provides me CRUD operations.
For example, the response for POST action is whole new item object:

```
{"Id":"7575c661-a40b-4161-b535-bd332edccc71","Text":"as","CreatedAt":"2018-09-13T15:29:52.7128732+00:00","LastChange":"2018-09-13T15:29:52.7128732+00:00"}
```

Now I need to use this Id in my frontend (to rewrite a temporary id I made on frontend until I receive confirmation that the upload was successful).
The problem comes with typescript when I type my thunk action "as I think it's right":

```
export const uploadItem = (fetch: (text: string) => Promise<Item>) =>
(generateId: () => ItemId) =>
 (text: string) =>
  async (dispatch: Dispatch<ThunkAction<IAction, IAppState, void>>): Promise<IAction> => {
    const id = generateId();
    try {
      dispatch(addItem(id, text));
      const itemWithOfficialId = await fetch(text);
      dispatch(synchronizeItemId(id, itemWithOfficialId.id));
      return dispatch(setAsSynchronized(itemWithOfficialId.id));
    } catch {
      return dispatch(requestFailedForItem(id, errorMessageTypes.UPLOAD, 'Failed to upload. '));
    }
  };
```

The problem I see is on the first line:

```
fetch: (text: string) => Promise<Item>
```

that forces me to do:

```
itemWithOfficialId.id
```

because my `Item` has only property `id` and I need to extract `Id`.
But typescript won't let me change it to `itemWithOfficialId.Id`.

I know I could make a new Item model, that would consist of properties returned from the server and use it like `Promise<ItemFromServer>`, but it feels a bit cheesy to me and I wanted to know if there was another way how to convert these without creating a new representation of the same object?

Comment: So, the Item object has more properties than Id, Text, CreatedAt and LastChange?

Answer (score 1):

If you have two objects with different sets of properties, even if the property names differ only in case, I don't think you can get around declaring two different types.  However, there are tools such as [Typewriter](https://frhagn.github.io/Typewriter/) that you may be able to use to generate the `ItemFromServer` declaration automatically from your server code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I guess you are right. First I thought that it is done automatically somehow because my program worked before, but then I found out I was converting it by myself in reducer O:) so I resolved it by converting it in reducer too.